# AntD - Column render using only text and index

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Currently, I have the render function for a column in this form:

```js
title: 'POLL',
dataIndex: 'poll',
render: (text: string, record: any, index: number) => {...}
```

I just want to use text and index, and I don't want unused arguments. Moreover, text is supposed to be a string but when I use `typeof` on text, it results in `object`.

Comment: You must be passing columns value as an object. Just check once, if poll has the text value or not in the data source.
And you can not avoid the params, you just have to ignore the param.

Comment: You're right. The passed value is an object. Shouldn't typescript throw an error, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing *incorrect* about unused arguments, especially when dealing with a third party interface that you don't control. However, you could use the rest operator:

```js
render: (...args) => {
  //args[0] is text
  //args[1] is record
  //args[2] is index
}
```

The issue here is that your types no longer apply explicitly, but I think the types are still inferred.

I'm not sure why you're getting an object as a string argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Yes, unused arguments aren't incorrect but I just wanted to avoid them. And `text` is object because passed value was an object (should've thrown a warning or something).